# Foreign Key update using JdbcTemplate is very slow in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am using `Spring JdbcTemplate` to update the Foreign key relationship, Primary Key of Department table has to be referred to Employee Table. One department can have same but multiple employees working in.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("positionJdbcTemplate")
private JdbcTemplate positionJdbcTemplate;

@Override
public void write(List<? extends Department> items) throws Exception {

    List<Object[]> batch = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Department d : items) {
        batch.add(new Object[]{d.getDepartmentId(), d.getIdentifyingParam()});
    }

    int[] ints = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(SQL, batch, new int[]{Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR});
    log.info("## data saved to Postgres DB = {}", ints.length);
}
```

Its taking 1 minutes to load the 999 records, attached Primary Key (PK) of Department Table to multiple rows of employee table. How can we improve that?

Comment: Why on earth do you need to load all departments to "maintain" a foreign key?  An employee can only reference a single department.  Building your batch list might be a bit faster if you make it immediately of an appropriate size.

Comment: I can't help myself because data is like that only, & I need to somehow find the solution

Comment: "I can't help myself because data is like that only"  ???    You could use a prepared statement in the batchupdate:  https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/